# Offline HTTPS test?

Tags: firefox, ssl

Clients cannot connect with webbrowser since they just get:

SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT

but we cannot figure out, what is the issue with the HTTPS cert.

Since the HTTPS site is internal, not public

**question:** is there any similar method like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ - just "offline" for internal websites?

Comment: curl -v https://your.intra.site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Linux machine in your local network (or if not, just set up a VM – or use the provided Docker file to generate a Docker container), you could take a look at **[testssl.sh](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh)** – which is a command-line tool to check SSL setups. It's quite flexible, can be adjusted via command-line parameters, scan against any port (not just 443) – and can even generate "machine readable output" (CSV, JSON). Run the script without any parameter (or just pass `--help`) to get a list of options. Or simply pass it the URL to your server to get a full report, e.g. `./testssl.sh https://example.com/`.

Note that the handshake error usually is no issue with the cert, but with incompatible cipher suites or protocols. The output of `testssl.sh` is quite extensive, and certainly should give you some clues.